# Finding if user input has key words from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code:

```
positiveList = ['love', 'nice', 'relaxing', 'okay']
negativeList = ['hate', "don't like", 'not good']

print "How is the weather?"

answer = str(raw_input())

if answer in positiveList:
    print "Pass"
else:
    print "FAIL"
```

What I'm trying to figure out is if the user input: 'i love it'
then I'd be able to check that the string 'love' is in my list and continue from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use sets, then no looping or list comprehension is necessary:

```
positiveList = set(('love', 'nice', 'relaxing', 'okay'))

print "How is the weather?"
answer = str(raw_input()).lower()

if set(answer.split()).intersection(positiveList):
    print "Pass"
else:
    print "FAIL"
```

The method `intersection` looks for any words in `answer` that are also in `positiveList`.  If any are found, then the intersection of the two sets is nonempty and therefore, as an `if` condition, evaluates as `True`.

#### Sample run

```
How is the weather?
I Love It
Pass
```

#### More on sets and `intersection`

Let's create a set from the answer above:

```
>>> x = set('i love it'.split())
>>> x
set(['i', 'love', 'it'])
```

Now, let's get its intersection with the positiveList:

```
>>> positiveList = set(('love', 'nice', 'relaxing', 'okay'))
>>> x.intersection(positiveList)
set(['love'])
```

The `intersection` of two sets is whatever elements (in this case, words) both sets have in common.  Here, they had the word `love` in common.  Thus, the `intersection` of the two sets is a set with the word `love`.

Here is an example of two sets that have no words in common:

```
>>> set(['not good']).intersection(positiveList)
set([])
```

And, here is an example where they have two words in common:

```
>>> set(['not good', 'love', 'nice']).intersection(positiveList)
set(['love', 'nice'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry i just got home from work. So I went ahead and gave it a go and it did work! I'd like to know more in depth of what can and can't be done with this 'intersection'. I found this method the easiest of those below. That goes without saying that those below also worked to which I very much appreciate the responses!

Comment: @Azhorabai Glad it worked for you.  I have added more examples of using `intersection`.

Comment: Omg, THANK YOU! Okay, so that honestly explained what my professor could not! So other than the purpose I'm using it for, what else could this be used for or better yet; What would this be used for in the real world?

Comment: @Azhorabai Suppose the school wants to schedule the chemistry final exam. at the same time as the calculus final exam. They want to know if that cause a conflict for any student.  So, take the _intersection_ of the _set_ of students taking chemistry and the _set_ of students taking physics.  If he intersection is empty, then there are no conflicts and it is OK to schedule  the finals at the same time.

Comment: wow, okay that was quite simple! :) You sir, have helped a young mind to continue his dreams of mastering his python understanding :) Thank you so much fo r all the help, I do not know how I can ever repay you, but if there be people who have questions that I know the answer to, I shall answer them! :D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the module re (I'd recommend it if you do that much with text), you could do this:

```
import re

positiveList = ['love','nice']
answer = input()
passList = [word for word in positiveList if re.search(word, answer)]
```

The line above assigns the words from postiveList which match a word in answer to passList. If you just want it to print 'PASS' (printing using this code is not recommended since you can't stop the process once you satisfy you're conditional statement), then change the last line to:

```
[print('PASS') for word in answer if re.search(word, answer)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code to:

```
positiveList = ['love', 'nice', 'relaxing', 'okay']
negativeList = ['hate', "don't like", 'not good']

print "How is the weather?"

answer = str(raw_input())
flag = 0
for word in positiveList:
    if word in answer:
        flag = 1
        break
if flag == 1:
    print "PASS"
else:
    print "FAIL"
```

Sample input and output:

```
How is the weather?
Its nice today.
PASS
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I did try it this way, how ever for simplistic sakes, I wanted something less, well wordy :p Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer:

```
positiveList = ['love', 'nice', 'relaxing', 'okay']
negativeList = ['hate', "don't like", 'not good']

print "How is the weather?"

answer = str(raw_input())

if any(word in answer for word in positiveList):
    print "Pass"
else:
    print "FAIL"
```

Note that "nicely" will "pass" in this code. (It just looks to see if "nice" appears anywhere in the string.)

An alternative would be to split the sentence into words and check each word in the sentence to see if it's in the `positiveList`. Here's code that does that in a sort of weak way... note that it will get confused by things like punctuation. (Splitting "It's nice!" into words this way will give you `["It's", "nice!"]`, and neither one of those is in the list.)

```
positiveList = ['love', 'nice', 'relaxing', 'okay']
negativeList = ['hate', "don't like", 'not good']

print "How is the weather?"

answer = str(raw_input())

words = answer.split()

if any(word in positiveList for word in words):
    print "Pass"
else:
    print "FAIL"
```

Comment: would this method not be similar to that of what @John1024 stated?
    answer = str(raw_input()).lower()
i mean, instead of doing that instead of creating
    words = answer.split()
Could we not do
    if any(word in positiveList for word in answer):
        print "Pass"

Comment: You'd need to do `for word in answer.split()`.

Answer (score -1):

This statement, # if answer in positiveList: is incorrect because if you type "i love it," it will compare the whole phase with the list. Use smarx's method.